# php : getting Resource id #6 in email

Tags: php, email

i've tested this code to send emails using a tool for local server and it works fine, but in the "from" section i didn't get the sender email as it supposed to print there as a result to $email , instead i got this output " From: Resource id #6 " , what's the problem exactly coz the query seems fine and working ?

this part of the code

```
$Load=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$smail= "Select email from teacher where TID = $Load ";

$errors = '';
  $email= mysql_query($smail);  
if( 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}


$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $email_address; 
    $email_subject = "New mail from admin";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n From: $email \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $email\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    $sent = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);      
}
```

Comment: where u trying this code i mean on local host ?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is this your first time using mysql_ functions? Do yourself a favour, switch over to PDO and prepared statements. For a more immediate solution, read the [documentation page for `mysql_query`](http://us.php.net/mysql_query#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues), it spells out what this function returns and how that return value should be used.

Comment: @DCoder no, coz all my project i've used mysql_ :(

Answer (score 1):

You are not fetching the record after executing query, try this

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($smail));  
$email = $result['email']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc

```
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($email));  
 $email = $result['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your result first.

```
$result= mysql_query($email);  
$row=mysql_fetch_object($result);
$email=$row->email;
```